# Programmatically flip through Metro FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'd like a FlipView to rotate through its items on a timer. The timer is easy, but is there a way to make the FlipView show the next item (and then loop around) in code?

The answer in this question [Why does FlipView ignore SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441408/why-does-flipview-ignore-selecteditem) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I needed to set both the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem for these FlipViews. Odd behaviour :/ (perhaps it is a change from RP to RTM - I am on RTM.)

Comment: Only one should be needed unless you are binding both which is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the SelectedItem property and use SelectedIndex instead. Set it to 0 to begin and just increase it by one until you reach the value equivalent to the number of items in the list minus one, then go back to zero. I just tested this and it works with flipview items declared in XAML or bound to the ItemsSource property.

Comment: Half the answer; I needed to set the SelectedItem as well as the index. Which version are you running? I'm on RTM tools. Have an upvote anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you are notifying the UI that the property changed. Your ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and the property needs to fire the PropertyChanged event

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object _selectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedItem = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the BindableBase class comes with the sample apps

```
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private object _selectedItem;

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return this._selectedItem; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._selectedItem, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm well experienced in this now - but it will be a useful answer for new devs anyway. Have an upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

This may help in some situations

```
flipView.SelectedIndex = -1;
flipView.SelectedIndex = desiredIndex;
```

OR

```
flipView.SelectedItem = null;
flipView.SelectedItem = flipViewItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 VS2017
For the following XML code:

```
<FlipView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="fvMainControls">
    <FlipViewItem>
        <CheckBox Content="My Overlay" Height="21" Canvas.Left="191" Canvas.Top="164" Width="131"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="387" Margin="54,140,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="206" Fill="#FF6A1717" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFA46767"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

This works:

```
fvMainControls.SelectedIndex = 0          
fvMainControls.SelectedIndex = 1
```

And

```
fvMainControls.SelectedItem = fvMainControls.Items(0)
fvMainControls.SelectedIndex = fvMainControls.Items(1)
```

works. Ravi